# Danglings Pointers and Delete Command in C++

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer

I noticed something very strange in my C++ code.

```
class A
{
    public:
    void doIt(){cout<<"hello"<<endl;}
};
int main() {
    A* a=new A();
    A* b=a;
    delete a;
    b->doIt();
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that `delete` will erase the memory from the heap and `b->doIt()` would fail. But while running this code it works and even print "hello".

Why?

Comment: It might appear to "work" but it is still undefined behaviour. Don't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that delete will erase the memory from the heap

The only way you can "erase" memory is with a hammer.

The memory is marked as "unused" and the *object* is destroyed, semantically.

> and `b->doIt()` would fail

Why's that?

There is no mechanism in place to do that for you, nor *can there* be one in the general case.

It's *your* responsibility not to call functions on objects that don't exist.

Speaking practically, it doesn't crash here because nothing in `doIt` actually attempts to access the object's memory. Remember, the function isn't stored "in" the object — it's part of your program, and your program still exists.

Even if `doIt` accessed and/or mutated the object's state, as long as that memory were still in the active page, you'd probably *still* not get a crash. This is precisely why *undefined behaviour* is defined to be unpredictable.

Avoid.

---

- **Similar:**  [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/560648)

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely because `doIt` method doesn't use any internal state of the A class. Compiler therefore probably optimised it to a static method and the call is invoked in a static class context. The fact that the pointer is dangling then do not prevent the method from being run.

However, it is undefined behaviour and more strict compilers might actually produce a code that indeed fails.

Comment: Almost - in fact there's no need for the compiler to "optimise it to a static method" (it probably didn't do that). The key is that the `this` pointer simply never needs to be "actually" dereferenced in this program. And, even if it were, it still probably wouldn't crash tbh.